# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of

Tags: php, laravel

I have Created a new middleware for checking the user token I have create middleware then adeded to kernal.php and but when i tried to access $request in middleware i am getting the error

Here is my is my middleware code

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Closure;
use App\User;

class CheckToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if($request->header('Token') == '123')
        {
            return ['status' =>2, 'msg' => 'Unathorized'];
        }
        else
        {
            return $next($request);
         }

    }
}
```

Here is my kernal file

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'verifyToken' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckToken::class,
    ];
```

**and I am getting this error**

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\idoltime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php on line 62
```

Comment: Try clearing laravel log files, I was tricked by this situation lately and found single day log file was having 70k+ lines of entries.

Answer (score 13):

You may use

```
// return $request;
if($request->header('Token') == '123')
{
        $response = [
            'status' => 2,
            'message' => 'Unauthorized',
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 413);
}
else
{
        return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem but not find any answer on the internet. Here is the solution to how I solved this issue.

**Step 1: Create a separate route for example**

```
Route::get('header_token', function() {
  return response()->json(['status' =>2, 'msg' => 'Unathorized']);
})->name('header_token');
```

**Step 2: Redirect to header_token route**

*keep in mind you can not return data as response, so return to a route that will return your data*

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if($request->header('Token') == '123')
    {
        return redirect(route('header_token'));
    }
    else
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (auth()->user()) {
    return $next($request);
}else{
    return JsonResponse::respondError("you are not active email");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem like this

```
exit(response()->json( json_encode(['message' => 'Text']), 403) );

echo() - var_dump() - print() - print_r() - also works too...
```

Comment: Абдушакур Савзаев, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).