# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of please sir

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

have Created a new middleware for checking the user token I have create middleware then adeded to kernal.php and but when i tried to access $request in middleware i am getting the error

Here is my is my middleware code

please help

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $token = $request->header('Authorization');
    $verify = explode(" ", $token);

    if ($verify[0] !== "petani") {

        return [
            'code' => 401,
            'error' => 'Token not provided.'
        ];
    }

    if (!$token) {

        return [
            'code' => 400,
            'error' => 'Provided token is expired.'
        ];
    }

    try {
        
        $credentials = JWT::decode($verify[1], env('JWT_SECRET'), ['HS256']);
    
    } catch(ExpiredException $e) {

        return [
            'code' => 400,
            'error' => 'Token is expired. '
        ];
    } catch(Exception $e) {

        return [
            'code' => 400,
            'error' => 'An error while decoding token.'
        ];
    }

    return $next($request);

}
```

Comment: *must be an instance of please sir*? Is that the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972399/10573560):

you should return the response in this way:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $token = $request->header('Authorization');
        $verify = explode(" ", $token);

        if ($verify[0] !== "petani") {

            $response= [
                'code' => 401,
                'error' => 'Token not provided.'
            ];
            return response()->json($response, 401);
        }

        if (!$token) {

            $response= [
                'code' => 400,
                'error' => 'Provided token is expired.'
            ];
            return response()->json($response, 400);
        }

        try {

            $credentials = JWT::decode($verify[1], env('JWT_SECRET'), ['HS256']);

        } catch(ExpiredException $e) {

            $response= [
                'code' => 400,
                'error' => 'Token is expired. '
            ];
            return response()->json($response, 400);
        } catch(Exception $e) {

            $response= [
                'code' => 400,
                'error' => 'An error while decoding token.'
            ];
            return response()->json($response, 400);
        }

        return $next($request);

    }
```

Comment: guess what's wrong so this error occurs Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of